# How to express a permutation in terms of products of specific permutations?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Consider a permutation group generated by permutations $a=(1 2 3)$ and $b=(2 3 4)$. Given $(1 3 4)$ is an element of this permutation group, how to express it in terms of products of $a$ and $b$? (In this example the answer would be $baa$). I am asking for a general approach to solve the problem.

I know the solution is not unique, giving any would be fine but shorter would be preferred. There is a trivial solution by a BFS search of the tree of permutation product, return the results (if found) before exhausting all the elements of the group. But I would like to avoid that method because the order of the actual group I am working on is large.

Answer (score 2):

One general approach is to find a [base and strong generating set (BSGS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_generating_set), written in terms of the given basis. This can be done using the [Schreier-Sims Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier%E2%80%93Sims_algorithm) - you can find possibly nicer descriptions of these in *The Handbook of Computational Group Theory* by Holt or *Permutation Group Algorithms* by Seress.

A full description of what a BSGS is and how it can be used to write an arbitrary element in terms of generators can be found [here](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/rogers/talks/colloquium_13_jun_2014.pdf).